# How to autowire Spring service with Class name?

Tags: java, spring

I have multiple services and I want to autowire this services dynamically with using their class names. I have a method named "runCustomService" and this methods takes service's class names as input parameter (like "Service1" or "Service2"). I want to autowire these services and call its run method. Is there any way to do this?

```
@Service
public class Service1 extends BaseService{

    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    public void run(){ .... }
}

@Service
public class Service2 extends BaseService{

    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    public void run(){ .... }
}


public void runCustomService(String serviceClassName){        
    BaseService baseService = //Create baseService object from serviceClassName
    baseService.run();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use qualifiers on your two services and get the correct bean based on the qualifier name from the ApplicationContext.

```
@Service
@Qualifier("Service1")
public class Service1 extends BaseService{
```

```
@Service
@Qualifier("Service2")
public class Service2 extends BaseService{
```

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public void runCustomService(String serviceClassName){        
    BaseService baseService = applicationContext.getBean(serviceClassName);
    baseService.run();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Get an instance of ApplicationContext and get bean by a class name:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext ctx;
```

Use the method [getBean(...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-):

```
BaseService baseService = ctx.getBean(Service1.class.getName());
```

However, as the other answer says, I recommend you to use `@Qualifier(...)` to inject a certain named conditionally.